# Building an Expression for OrmLite with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm attempting to build an expression using `.And()` and pass to a  `db.Select<>()`.  The error thrown is:

> variable 'q' of type 'Proj1.Player' referenced from scope '', but
>   it is not defined

Code below:

```
Expression<Func<Player, bool>> exp = (q => q.ClientId == request.ClientId);

if (request.IsWinner.HasValue)
    if (request.IsWinner.Value)
    {
        if (game != null)
            exp = exp.And(q => q.WinHistory.Any(y => y.GameId == game.Id));
        else
            exp = exp.And(x => x.WinHistory.Any());
    }
    else
    {
        exp = exp.And(x => x.WinHistory.IsEmpty());
    }


var players = Db.Select<Player>(exp);
```

The base expression works properly. However, when combining it with the `.And()`, it throws the error.

Am I using this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't query on Collections to perform JOIN queries, you need to explicitly specify the JOIN query you want with something like:

```
if (request.Winner == true)
{
    q.Join<WinHistory>(); //uses implicit reference convention

    if (game != null)
        q.And<WinHistory>(w => w.GameId = game.Id);
}
else
{
    q.LeftJoin<WinHistory>()
     .And<WinHistory>(w => w.Id == null);
}

var players = db.Select(q);
```

The above makes use of OrmLite's [implicit reference convention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#reference-conventions) so you don't need to specify the join relation if it can be inferred. You can override this behavior by specifying an explicit join yourself.

#### Querying a blobbed Complex Type

As SQL doesn't allow querying of text blobs, if the WinHistory collection is instead a blobbed complex type, then you'll only be able to filter the collection on the client using Linq2Objects (i.e. after it's returned from the DB), e.g:

```
var players = db.Select<Player>(q => q.ClientId == request.ClientId);

if (request.IsWinner != null)
{
    players = request.IsWinner.Value
      ? players.Where(x => x.WinHistory.Any(y => y.GameId == game.Id)).ToList()
      : players.Where(x => x.WinHistory.Any().ToList()
}
else
{
    players = players.Where(x => x.WinHistory.IsEmpty());
}
```

Comment: My `WinHistory` is a serialized collection on `Player`...not a different table.  It shouldn't be doing a SQL Join anywhere.

Comment: @JeremySmith You can't perform a server query on a blobbed collection. You'd need Select the players without filtering then perform the filtering on the client.

Comment: That makes complete sense now that you mention it.  Present as answer if you can.